# Google Ads Sense does not showing on Magento Site

Tags: magento

I have added google adsense at the footer of my magento(1.5.1) site.but does not showing.After inspecting with firebug i got following error on console..

""NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?..."

I am using  both prototype & jquery in my site.my web site url http://medicalequipmentsupplies.co/.

I have tested google ad sense code i used is correct.

Please Help me...

Thanks

Comment: there is a '}' at the beginning of the page, remove it to see what happens

Comment: Hi,i have deleted the } but no change.

Comment: Are you using Magento extension to place Google Adsense? If so, which extension?